# Show that compact operator cannot have a bounded inverse on a infinite-dimensional Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis

Show that compact operator cannot have a bounded inverse on a infinite-dimensional Hilbert space.
Hint: use $A*A^{-1}=E$.

I've found a pretty useful topic here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_operator_on_Hilbert_space. Can someone explain it with $A*A^{-1}=E$.

Thank you.

Comment: Apply the identity from your hint to the unit ball. The right hand side will map it to itself, and if $A^{-1}$ were bounded, the image of the unit ball would be bounded, as well. Now apply the definition of compact operators.

Comment: The set of invertible operators is open in $B(H)$, whereas every compact operator is a limit of finite rank operators (for $H$ a Hilbert space!). If there were an invertible compact operator there must then be an invertible finite rank operator, which is preposterous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the properties of compact operators is that they form a two sided ideal in the algebra of bounded linear operators on $H$. If $T$ is compact and $S$ is any bounded linear operator (not necessary compact) then $TS$ and $ST$ are compact.

So if we assume  that $A$ is compact and invertible then $I=AA^{-1}$ must be compact as well. But there is a theorem which states that the identity operator in an infinite dimensional Banach space cannot be compact. So we get a contradiction.

Comment: Why if $A$ is compact and invertible then $I=AA^{-1}$ must be compact? Don't we have to prove that $A^{-1}$ is bounded?

Comment: @cciirrcclllee When I wrote "assume $A$ is invertible" I meant that we assume $A$ has a bounded inverse. Note that OP also asked specifically about why $A$ can't have a bounded inverse.

Comment: Nice proof using the fact that compact operators form a two-sided ideal! :)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $A$ is compact and $A$ has bounded inverse $A^{-1}$. Let $B(0,1)$ be the closed ball of radius $1$; we know that $A(B(0,1)$ is contained in a compact $C$, this implies that $A^{-1}(C)$ which contains $B(0,1)$ is compact since the image of a compact by a continuous map is compact, this impact that the closed unit ball is compact contradiction since the closed unit ball in an infinite dimensional Hilbert space is not compact.

Answer (score 0):

A more expository answer, even though both other answers are great:

If $T$ is a compact operator, then so is $TS$ for any bounded operator $S$. Taking $S=T^{-1}$ shows that the identity operator is compact. Therefore, every bounded sequence has a convergent subsequence. But we can use [Riesz's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%27s_lemma) that says

"If $X$ is a Banach space and $Y$ is a closed, proper subspace of $X$, then for each $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $x_\varepsilon\in X$ of norm $1$ such that $\text{dist}(x,Y)\geq1-\varepsilon$"

To construct a bounded sequence that has no convergent subsequences as follows:

Take $x_1\in X$ a unit vector in $X$ and set $Y=\text{span}\{x_1\}$. Then $Y$ is closed and proper (finite dimensional), so for $\varepsilon=1/2$ we get a unit vector $x_2$ such that $\text{dist}(x_2,Y)\geq1/2$. Thus $\|x_1-x_2\|\geq1/2$. Now do the same for $Y=\text{span}\{x_1,x_2\}$ to obtain $x_3\in X$ such that $\|x_3-x_1\|\geq1/2, \|x_3-x_2\|\geq1/2$. In this way we get a sequence $(x_n)$ of unit vectors such that for all $n,m$ it is $\|x_n-x_m\|\geq1/2$. This has the desired property.